Is there a way to automatically set the add_executable's target name to it's source file name in CMake?
I'm quite new to CMake. I want to get the executable for some CPP files with their filename as their executable filename. For example output1.cpp gives the executable named output1.
Currently I'm using the following lines in  my CMakeLists.txt file.
add_executable(output1 output1.cpp)
add_executable(output2 output2.cpp)
add_executable(output3 output3.cpp)
.
.
.    
add_executable(outputN outputN.cpp)

I know there is a for loop solution for this. Like,
foreach(i RANGE 1 N)
    add_executable(output${i} output${i}.cpp)
endforeach()

But that's not what I'm looking for. I'm looking for a solution that does not require passing hardcoded target names. Is there a way to achieve this?

Perhaps write your own little function/macro, which takes as input a filename and calls add_executable? Something like mycustom_executable( name ), which then calls add_executable( ${name} ${name}.cpp ). Or you could use get_filename_component with the NAME or NAME_WE argument.

Thank you for replying. I didn't know we can define functions in CMake up until now.. Creating a custom function sounds nice. I will try that. Thank you.

Why? That's quite a narrow corner case. Most, non trivial, C++ programs consist of docens or even hundreds or thousands of source files - which one should the executable be named after?

@JesperJuhl You're right. This is a trivial case. I was practicing boost tutorials. It required me to link multiple library files. So instead of making multiple CmakeList files I used the same CMake file, add the tutorial code to seperate c++ files named by their respective topics, and add their executables.

As @André  pointed out in the comments, I was able to solve this by declaring a custom auto_add_executable function.
function(auto_add_executable name)
    add_executable(${name} ${name}.cpp)
endfunction()

auto_add_executable(output1)
auto_add_executable(output2)
.
.
.
auto_add_executable(outputN)

